# Return ajax with if-else in response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, response

I'm using an ajax function to return different kind of values of a login.
And I'm trying to avoid three kinds of problem:

1 - If user's login is wrong

2 - If user's SN is wrong

3 - If user's password is wrong

In my php file I search if the data exists, if not, I'll send a type of error to the one which wasn't found:

```
  $connect = new database();    
   $info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myinfo WHERE myinfo.user_login = '$login_user'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($info) == 0) { 

        echo 'error_login'; 

    }

    $info2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myinfo WHERE myinfo.user_sn = '$sn_user'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($info2) == 0) { 

        echo 'error_sn'; 
    }

    $info3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myinfo WHERE myinfo.user_pw = '$user_pw'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($info3) == 0) { 

        echo 'error_pw'; 
    }
```

My ajax may receive three different responses:

```
      $.ajax({
                url:  "includes/enter.php",
                data: { 
                    login_user: $("#login").val(),
                    sn_user: $("#sn").val(),
                    user_pw: $("#pw").val()
                    },

                    success:function(response)
                    {  
                        if(response == "error_login")
                        {
                            alert("Invalid login!");
                        }
                        else if(response == "error_sn")
                        {
                            alert("Invalid SN!");
                        }
                        else if(response == "error_pw")
                        {
                            alert("Invalid password!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert("Success!");
                        }

                    }
            });
```

As Cpt.Kangar00 said, I used "==" (and is already edited). My main problem was that I nedded to use `echo`instead of `echo json_encode("error")`

Comment: `=` is assignment operator. `==` is comparison operator. Check your if conditionals

Comment: If I send you my username and password, your code checks if there is a) some user with my username and b) some (different?) user with my password, not that "the user with my username also has the password I sent".

Comment: Probably not your issue but why store the data in separate tables?

Comment: @chris85 I'm storing the data in different tables to give one response to each kind of error, so the user knows exactly what he typed wrong

Comment: From [Information Leakage and Improper Error Handling](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-Information_Leakage_and_Improper_Error_Handling) : ...supplying the same username but different passwords to a login function should produce the same text for no such user, and bad password. However, many systems produce different error codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either POST or GET to send the data, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  "data.php",
        data: { 
            user_login: $("#user_login").val(),
            user_sn: $("#user_sn").val(),
            user_pw: $("#user_pw").val(),
        },
        success:function(response)
        {  
            if(response == "error_login")
            {
                alert("Invalid login!");
            }
            else if(response == "error_sn")
            {
                alert("Invalid SN!");
            }
            else if(response == "error_pw")
            {
                alert("Invalid password!");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Success!");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And then access the data in PHP like so:

```
$user_login = $_POST['user_login'];
$user_sn = $_POST['user_sn'];
$user_pw = $_POST['user_pw'];

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=stackoverflow', 'root', '');

$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM myinfo WHERE user_login = :user_login");
$query->bindParam(':user_login', $user_login);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!$result) {
    echo json_encode('error_login');
    return;
}

$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM myinfo WHERE user_sn = :user_sn");
$query->bindParam(':user_sn', $user_sn);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!$result) {
    echo json_encode('error_sn');
    return;
}

$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM myinfo WHERE user_pw = :user_pw");
$query->bindParam(':user_pw', $user_pw);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!$result) {
    echo json_encode('error_sn');
    return;
}
```

Prepared statements are a much safer and more efficient way of running your database queries. This is an example script and will need cleaning up, but should serve as a good starting point for you. You can read more about PDO and prepared statements here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php.

Comment: Yes, I'm using connection before running them

Comment: @MattDAVM I have edited my answer and it is now a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You use "=" where you should use "==".

```
        $.ajax({
            url:  "includes/enter.php",
            data: { 
                login_user: $("#login").val(),
                sn_user: $("#sn").val(),
                user_pw: $("#pw").val()
                },

                success:function(response)
                {  
                    if(response == "error_login")
                    {
                        alert("Invalid login!");
                    }
                    else if(response == "error_sn")
                    {
                        alert("Invalid SN!");
                    }
                    else if(response == "error_pw")
                    {
                        alert("Invalid password!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Success!");
                    }

                }
        });
```

Comment: I used "==" and it still not working

Comment: I'm not sure how your returns work whether you have AJAX defaults, but if it would be de defaults, just remove the json_encodes in the PHP, so: echo json_encode('error_login'); will become echo 'error_login';

Comment: Now it worked, still quite suspect since I removed it a couple of times and still didn't get it. Well, I'll keep without the json_encode().